# How to monitoring Docker Container using OMD User

Tags: docker, nagios, check-mk

## OMD User

```
# omd create docker-user
# su - docker-user
```

1. How to monitor docker container?
2. Micro services memory usage inside the docker container?
3. How to configer docker container as  check_mk agent?

Iam using Check_mk for monitoring my servers and know want to monitor for docker as well?

Answer (score 0):

Here are two options:

1. when you deploy your container add the check_mk_agent at/during provisioning and using the Check_MK Web-API, add your host, do discovery, etc.
2. you can use the [following plugin](https://mathias-kettner.de/check_mk_exchange_file.php?HTML=yes&file=docker-1.2.4.mkp) to monitor docker containers.

Alternatively if you are using the enterprise version you can use the current innovation release (1.5.x) which has native Docker support.

Comment: 1.5.x has been release and you can now monitor docker containers without doing anything inside the container. Just deploy the check_mk_agent as usual on your docker hosts and you're set.

Answer (score 0):

This is a late answer but since this came on top of my Google search results, I will take some time to add up to Marius Pana's answer. As of now, the raw version of Check_MK also supports natively dockers. However, if you want dedicated checks inside your docker, you will need to actually install a Check_MK agent inside the docker. To do that, you need to start some sort of shell (generally sh or bash) inside the docker with `docker exec -it <id> sh`. You can get your docker ID with `docker ps`.

Now that's the easy part. The hard part is to figure out which package manager you are dealing with inside the docker (if any) and how to install inetd/xinetd or your preferred way of communication for your agent (unless it's already installed). If it's a Ubuntu-based image, you will generally need to start with a `apt update`, `apt-get install xinetd` and then you can install your packaged Check_MK agent or install it manually if you prefer. If it's a CentOS-based image, you will instead use `yum`. If the image is based on Arch Linux, you will probably want to use `pacman`.

Once you managed to install everything in your docker, you can test by adding your docker IP to Check_MK as a host. Please note that if your docker is using the host IP, you will need to forward port 6556 from your docker to another port on your host since I assume you're already monitoring the host through port 6556.

After you've checked everything is working, 2 more things. If you stop there, a simple restart of your docker will cancel every change you've made, so you need to do a `docker commit` to save your changes to your container image. And lastly, you will want to plan container updates ahead: you can do reinstall the agent every time a new version of the container is pulled (you could even script this), or you could add instructions to your `cont-init.d` which would be executed every time you launch your docker.